# Store information in a universal way so users can't edit it

Tags: c#, database, file, interop, format

I'm building an application in C# that will use 'databases', but I want to be able to access the content of the 'database'/file in as many programming languages. The 'database' basically needs to be like a dictionary (it isn't one though), so like `word=meaning`, and I don't mind too much if a user can openly edit that.

However, there's a few things I want to store in the database that the user should not be able to edit. For example, I would like to store a unique key that the application will analyse and compare. I'd also like to add an 'isEditable' property that tells the application whether or not it can change the database, but this is not essential.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could store this information? I thought about XML because I could just hash the unique key, but I don't think it would be suitable for the `word=meaning` part.

Comment: Have you considered using an actual 'database'?

Comment: What about... emmm... an actual database?

Comment: "but I don't think it would be suitable for the word=meaning part." - why would you think that? `<Dict><Entry word="" meaning="" /><Entry word="" meaning="" />[...]</Dict>`

Comment: What type of database would you suggest though? And @Corak, thanks for the suggestion - that's a good idea. Completely forgot you could do that.... Is there any format I could use so that it is hard for users to edit manually though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are plenty of options. You can use a traditional database, and restrict user privileges. That way, the users can't edit anything (or can only do what ever permissions you grant them). If this needs to be deployed with your application, you can use a compact DB, like Sqlite or SQL Server Compact. There are ways to encrypt the entire DB file or to password protect them, so that would prevent your users from editing them. Sqlite has providers for many languages.

You could try a non-traditional database, like a MongoDB or [db4objects](http://www.db4o.com/). The latter uses a type of binary serialization so that you can persist  your code objects to disk. Again, not easily user-editable. You could just persist your collection. With the former, you'll be closer to your goal of key=value pairs, because you don't have to have a defined schema for either of these options.

An XML file could work, provided you encrypted it, if your goal is to make it non-user-editable.

Comment: Hmmm... Regarding the traditional database option, even if I restrict the privileges couldn't the file be opened in something like Notepad++ and just change the queries, like with `.sql` files? I'm really not sure about encryption though because at the end of the day there are no secrets in there, apart from the ones which can be hashed, and it seems that most of the bigger softwares just use XML or something similar. Would it be a bad idea to change the `.xml' extension though, even if it's still an XML file?

Comment: No, databases are not stored in a text-editable format. The .SQL files you're thinking of are saved queries, not database files themselves. Queries are text, but the data itself is stored in a binary representation. As to the rest, a lot of those "bigger softwares" use XML for things like configuration. If you want to be able to hand-edit your data, XML isn't a bad idea. Extensions don't matter to your program, but any user could still open any file with any program. So changing the file extension is not security. Using a  proper database is.

Comment: Thank you very much for that clarification. In that case, if I was only detering the editing of data, I wouldn't even need to encrypt the database, especially if I hashed anything that I could. However, do you know if you can encrypt SQLite databases in C#.NET?

Comment: I've never done it with Sqlite, but I've used SQL Server CE and done that successfully: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237941(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Ok, so is there anything I need to consider before I start using SQL Server CE? For example, what are the end-user requirements and what programming languages are able to decrypt and read the databases?

Comment: I'd suggest searching out SQL CE and researching these issues yourself. As to what can connect to it...I only work with .NET. I know that there are already .NET providers that can use SQL CE, but it's a microsoft product and MS languages are probably going to be the best supported. Sqlite is more broadly supported, but I don't have enough first-hand experience with it to say much.

Comment: I'd suggest searching out SQL CE and researching these issues yourself. As to what can connect to it...I only work with .NET. I know that there are already .NET providers that can use SQL CE, but it's a microsoft product and MS languages are probably going to be the best supported. Sqlite is more broadly supported, but I don't have enough first-hand experience with it to say much.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34016/discussion-between-curtis-rutland-and-andy)

Comment: Ok, I will continue on the chat tomorrow (I'm in the UK) but unfortunately I have to sign off until the morning now. Thank you for your help so far